# Generalization of standard deviation?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics

Standard deviation is often taken from a one-dimensional list of numbers. However, how would one evaluate standard deviation of a set of points of $N$-dimensional coordinates?

Comment: [Covariance matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Definition_of_sample_covariance) contain information about variability in each component as well as dependence between components.

Comment: @angryavian: I would say it contains information on correlation between components instead of the more general dependence concept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct Intuition? Standard Deviation and distance in $n$ dimensional space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418801/correct-intuition-standard-deviation-and-distance-in-n-dimensional-space)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a tensor instead of a matrix in the more general case? Or if there's two coordinates I would use 2x2 matrices?

Comment: @PhiEarl Covariance matrices only contain information about pairwise dependence between components, so it is an $N \times N$ matrix. For higher-order dependence involving more than two variables, I suppose the generalization would involve higher-order moments and would result in a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined as $\sqrt{|\Sigma|}$ where $|\Sigma|$ is the determinant of the variance-covariance matrix, a $N\times N$ matrix with the single variances on the main diagonal and covariances elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is a random point in $\mathbb R^{n\times1}.$ Then $\mu = \operatorname E(X) \in \mathbb R^{n\times1}$ is defined componentwise and then
$$
\Sigma = \operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname E\big((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top\big) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$
is an $n\times n$ nonnegative-definite symmetric matrix.

It can be shown via the (finite-dimensional version of the) spectral theorem that $\Sigma$ has a nonnegative-definite symmetric square root $\Sigma^{1/2}$ (definitely *not* defined componentwise).

If $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times n}$ then
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = A\Sigma A^\top \in\mathbb R^{k\times k}.
$$
From this it follows that if $\operatorname{var}(Y) = I_n$ (the $n\times n$ identity matrix) and $\Sigma$ is any nonnegative-definite symmetric real matrix, then $\Sigma^{1/2} Y$ has variance $\Sigma,$ and therefore **every** nonnegative-definite symmetric real matrix is a variance.

If $\Sigma$ is invertible then it can be shown that a random vector whose density is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}^{\,n}} \frac 1 {\big(\det\Sigma^{1/2}\big)} \exp\left( - \frac 1 2 (x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu) \right)
$$
has expected value $\mu$ and variance $\Sigma.$